# Can't execute method on main thread after Task.Run

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

Unity version: 2022.1.18f1

I have the code below which creates a list of tasks on the background thread using `Task.Run`. I set `tasksReadyToConsume` to true once the operation is finished. I'm trying to create the tasks using `Task.Run` because they cause a major spike and they need to be called (task list is recreated) every 5 seconds which I'm doing using `InvokeRepeating`.

Then I try to complete all tasks in `Update()` which should always run on the main thread using `Task.WhenAll`. However I still get this error:

*UnityEngine.UnityException: RandomRangeInt can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.*

None of the code in the tasks is using Unity RandomRange... There's only a `WWWForm` and `UnityWebRequest` in these methods. Trying to call this from the background thread throws the same error.

I also tried PimDeWitte's MainThreadDispatcher, it didn't work with the same error.

```
await Task.Run(() => CreateTaskList());
await UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().EnqueueAsync(async () => await CompleteTasks());
```

https://github.com/PimDeWitte/UnityMainThreadDispatcher

Unity seems to not be able to consume the tasks on the main thread even in its own Update cycle which is supposed to always run on the main thread.

Any ideas on how to get this to work without having the major CPU spike caused by `CreateTaskList()` would be appreciated.

```
    List<Task> chainDataTaskList;
    
    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating(nameof(UpdateData), 0f, 5f);
    }

    private async void Update()
    {
        // trigger once on main thread
        if(tasksReadyToConsume && chainDataTaskList.Count == 5)
        {
            await CompleteTasks();
            tasksReadyToConsume = false;
            Debug.Log("Tasks consumed");
        }
    }
    
    bool getDataLocked;

    async Task UpdateData()
    {
        if (getDataLocked)
        {
            return;
        }

        getDataLocked = true;
        await Task.Run(() => CreateTaskList());
    }

    void CreateTaskList()
    {
        chainDataTaskList = new List<Task>()
        {
              // General contract data
              ChainFunctions.OwnedTokenIDs(s_chain, s_network, s_contract, s_account),
              ChainFunctions.GetStatBigInt("getCostForAddress", new string[] { s_account }),
              ChainFunctions.GetStatNoParams("totalSupply"),
              ChainFunctions.GetStatNoParams("maxSupply"),
              ChainFunctions.GetBoolNoParams("paused")
        };

        tasksReadyToConsume = true;
        Debug.Log("Task List Creation Finished");
    }

    async Task CompleteTasks()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(chainDataTaskList);

            // General contract data
            updatedOwnedTokensList = await (Task<List<int>>)chainDataTaskList[0];
            dynamicMintCost = await (Task<System.Numerics.BigInteger>)chainDataTaskList[1];
            totalSupply = await (Task<int>)chainDataTaskList[2];
            maxSupply = await (Task<int>)chainDataTaskList[3];
            paused = await (Task<bool>)chainDataTaskList[4];
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            getDataLocked = false;
            Debug.LogError(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Adding a screenshot of the spike from the profiler. This is running `CreateTaskList()` on the main thread.
[image: Main Thread]

Comment: One thing to realize is that running your tasks on another thread won't necessarily prevent CPU spikes since any CPU-bound work would still be CPU-bound.

Comment: Beside 'Debug.Log()' unity function are not thread safe and cannot be called from other threads or will most likely result in a crash.

Comment: _"RandomRangeInt can only be called from the main thread"_ - that's not surprising.  Many GPU-related operations (and this isn't specific to Unity/DirectX but also OpenGL) must be performed from the Main Thread.  In Unity for example _["The C# API's for Texture creation (E.g. new Texture2D) must always be called on the main thread"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture-allowThreadedTextureCreation.html)_.  So it doesn't matter what technique you use to _spin up threads._